# Adding objects to an arraylist in a for loop, but arraylist is empty after for loop is done?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm a beginner so I feel like I might be making a silly mistake. Basically, I am running through a for loop and with each iteration, it is creating a new Event object and adding it to the arraylist called eventsList.

I have added a print statement at the bottom of each for loop iteration and it tells me that the size of eventsList is increasing: 1,2,3..

but for the second print statement, out of the for loop it tells me that the size is 0 (the second print statement which says: "size is...")

```
ListView eventsListView;
ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
Event event = null;

public void update() {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException exception) {
            if (exception != null) {
                return
            }

            if (objects.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("objects empty");
                return
            }

            System.out.println("objects size > 0");

            for (ParseObject object: objects) {

                String address = object.getString("address");
                String name = object.getString("name");
                String date = object.getString("date");
                String time = object.getString("time");
                String description = 
                object.getString("description");

                event = new Event(name, date, address);
                eventList.add(event);
                System.out.println(eventList.size());

            }
        }
    });

    System.out.println("The size is: " + eventList.size());

}
```

Comment: Use Log instead of print for debugging in android. Post your log after changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your code, but the issue here is that when the `The size is:` print statement is hit, the background task which actually populates the event list may not yet have completed.  So, the change you need to make to your code is a logical one, in which you only attempt to use the populated list *after* the background task has finished.  The place to do that is in the `done()` method.